# Java classes and object to databases

Tags: java, database, spring

I am studying java and web applications on my own and I'm totally stuck with this exercise. I know something about java and objects but I can't wrap my head around these "classes representing databases" and entities concepts.
The assignment is:
*The assignment template has the entities for managing accounts and clients, but they are missing a connection. Modify the application so that a customer may have multiple accounts, but each account belongs only to a single client. Adding an account must also add the account to a client.*

And code can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/LYY9PHzw
What I understand is:
1. index.html gives variables **name** and **iban**
2.BankingController.java creates Client object with variable name and Account object with variable iban and sets balance to 100.
3. Then I should add account object to client objects ArrayList named accounts.

Then classes Client and Account should be transformed to database Tables and added to Repositories and that client table and account table have OneToMany and ManyToOne relations.
If someone could help me with this. If I get this application to work, I could figure out, how it works.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is, how do I get it to work?